# What is the meaning of Chrome's IndexedDB error "Internal error checking key existence"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I'm getting this error message intermittently within a relatively large project at seemingly arbitrary times (which makes me suspect a race condition somewhere...), so I unfortunately don't have a minimal example illustrating this problem as I do not understand the root cause. Basically, sometimes I get an error signal where `event.target.webkitErrorMessage` is "Internal error checking key existence". But I don't really understand what this error message is even supposed to mean.

[Googling for this phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Internal+error+checking+key+existence%22) returns only 7 results (although it will be more once Google and others find this question). These results are all either Chromium source code or bug reports about adding more detailed error messages to Chromium. As I am not intimately familiar with Chromium's IndexedDB backend implementation, one thing I'm struggling to understand is what this error message means in terms of frontend JavaScript code. For instance, what kinds of JavaScript mistakes can lead to that error message?

The code in question seems to work fine in Firefox, FWIW.

**EDITS BELOW**

I also, more rarely, get null returned as a cursor in response to an `openCursor` request for a key that I know is a real key. This is also inconsistent - it happens for different keys and rarely. And it's also only in Chrome. Very bizarre.

And I'm not sure if it's relevant, but this all happens within a large transaction with many `update`s in two object stores (these are the ones leading to the null `openCursor` problems) and many `add`s in another object store (this seems to be the source of the "Internal error checking key existence" error). I will try to make a minimal example of this and investigate further, but regardless of how that turns out, I'd still like to know the answer to my original question, which is what specifically "Internal error checking key existence" means.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

After playing around some more, I ran into another weird transient error message, "Internal error: backing store error performing put/add". I'd also be curious about what that implies about my JavaScript.

Also, I validated that all of these problems are new to Chrome 26 (and remain in Chrome 27). Downgrading to Chrome 25 makes all these problems disappear... so maybe this is all just from some bug in Chrome...

**ONE MORE EDIT**

All of these problems seem to only happen in Linux (I'm using Ubuntu 12.10). In a Windows XP VM with Chrome 26, I can't reproduce any of these errors. I [submitted a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227313) as it's becoming increasingly clear that this is all due to some bug, but I'm not sure if I've narrowed down the issue enough to help find a solution.

Comment: When you receive that error ? `onerror` callback of the `IDBRequest` ? Have you also check `request.error` or `event.target.error` ? The only valid IndexedDB API error is `ConstraintError`, as I recall.

Comment: Yes, it's in the `onerror` callback for `IDBRequest`. `event.target.error.name` says it's an `UnknownError` (I don't think `ConstraintError` is the only possible value, since in addition to this one, I also see `AbortError`s for requests after the transaction is aborted). [`event.target.webkitErrorMessage` provides some extra detail](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104199), but like I described in my post, its error messages don't seem to be usefully documented.

Comment: Thanks for excellent explanation and probe. `UnknownError` are IO error, isn't? I also encountered Chrome only problem on large or multiple transactions. If I could reproduce them, I will file a bug to chromium project. So far still trying to reproduce in the form of unit test. It can easily reproduce on the app however. Workaround is as easy as making transaction short.

Comment: Short transactions hurt performance. On the plus side, I realized that these error messages only appear in Linux, so it won't affect 99% of my users. I did [submit a bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227313) based on this since it pretty clearly is a bug given that the same code works in other browsers, other versions of Chrome, and the same version of Chrome in Windows; but I'm not sure if I've done enough preliminary work to make it a useful bug report. It's really hard to make a short unit test because the frequency of errors decreases rapidly as it becomes simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in an edit to the question, I submitted [a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227313). It has seemingly been resolved in Chrome 28. So anyone experiencing this problem in older versions of Chrome, just upgrade to the unstable version or wait a couple months for Chrome 28 to be stable. And if anyone gets errors like this in Chrome 28 or higher, it's likely a bug.